# Solving simultaneous equations via $u$ and $v$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, self-learning

I'm self-studying from Stroud's amazing "Engineering Mathematics" textbook, and have run into an issue in one of the final end-of-chapter exercises for in the "Linear Equations" chapter.

Here's the problem:

Writing $u$ for $\dfrac{1}{x+8y}$ and $v$ for $\dfrac{1}{8x-y}$, solve the following equations for $u$ and $v$, and hence determine the values of $x$ and $y$:

$$\frac{2}{x+8y} - \frac{1}{8x-y} = 4;$$
$$\frac{1}{x+8y} + \frac{2}{8x-y} = 7$$

So far, in my solution I have

$$2u - v = 4$$
$$u + 2v = 7$$

Multiplying the first one by 2:

$$4u - 4v = 8$$
$$u + 4v = 7$$

Subtracting, we can find the value of $u$:
$$5u = 15$$
**$$u = 3$$**

Now we can easily find the value of $v$:

$$4v = 7 - u$$
$$4v = v$$
**$$v = 4$$**

So, my question is - what next?

Comment: Now you know the values of $x+8y$ and $8x-y$ !

Comment: Substitute back in! This is the easiest part! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $u = \frac{1}{x + 8y}$, instead of $u = \frac{1}{x+8}.$

I did not check your computations, but the approach remains the same. You have found that 
$$\begin{cases}
u = 3 &= \frac{1}{x+8y}\\
v = 4 &= \frac{1}{8x-y}
\end{cases}$$
This implies that 
$$\begin{cases}
x + 8y &= \frac{1}{3}\\
8x-y &= \frac{1}{4}
\end{cases}.$$
Can you take it from here?